# Where can I find Apple api list?

Tags: ios, api, appstore-approval

I've heard that apple app store checks app before storing it to the app store.

When checking the apps, Apple refuses to store it if the app has apis that is not allowed.

I want to know where to get this refusable api list.

Comment: There is no list of private APIs - because they are private.  As long as you only use APIs that are documented in the Apple class references you are OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You´re right this is something that Apples is checking and I don't think there's a list since this gets updated all the time but

- Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected
- Apps that use location-based APIs for automatic or autonomous control of vehicles, aircraft, or other devices will be rejected
- Apps that use location-based APIs for emergency services will be rejected
- Apps that provide Push Notifications without using the Apple Push Notification (APN) API will be rejected
- Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected
- Apps must not use data gathered from the HomeKit APIs for advertising or other use-based data mining
- Apps using data gathered from the HomeKit API for purposes other than improving the user experience or hardware/software performance in providing home automation functionality will be rejected
- Apps may not use or disclose to third parties user data gathered from the HealthKit API or from health-related human subject research for advertising or other use-based data mining purposes other than improving health, or for the purpose of health research
- Apps that share user data acquired via the HealthKit API with third parties without user consent will be rejected

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)