# Apple Store review guidelines, capabilities

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

My app uses `remote push notifications`, It works fine in the app. The app dosent have any crashes or anything like that using push notifications (from parse.com). as you can see at 
    [1:18](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hn-fEE0Owr0).

I have followed the tutorial on `Parse` for setting up `push notifications`. I have developer provisioning profiles and enabled push notifications on my app Id. But do I need to set remote notifications and push notifications on in capabilities, before sending it in for review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be good to go and send your app for review!

If you have push notification these are the things that Apple can reject your app for:

1. Apps that provide Push Notifications without using the Apple Push Notification (APN) API will be rejected
2. Apps that use the APN service without obtaining a Push Application ID from Apple will be rejected
3. Apps that send Push Notifications without first obtaining user consent, as well as apps that require Push Notifications to function, will be rejected
4. Apps that send sensitive personal or confidential information using Push Notifications will be rejected
5. Apps that use Push Notifications to send unsolicited messages, or for the purpose of phishing or spamming will be rejected
6. Apps cannot use Push Notifications to send advertising, promotions, or direct marketing of any kind
7. Apps cannot charge users for use of Push Notifications
8. Apps that excessively use the network capacity or bandwidth of the APN service or unduly burden a device with Push Notifications will be rejected
9. Apps that transmit viruses, files, computer code, or programs that may harm or disrupt the normal operation of the APN service will be rejected

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#push-notifications).

Good luck with the review!

Comment: but what does number one mean, and do i satisfy that?

Comment: If you use some private API´s and not Apples @trw

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: i followed the Parse setup, does that mean i use apples API?

Comment: No Parse should be ok, checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34555116/5576310) post for some more information.